# How to avoid sym_ tables in slave side database in symmetricDs configuration?

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication, symmetricds

I have master node and salve node running on the same system replicate from the master to the slave, when i start the system it will generate sym_ tables on both master and slave nodes .Is it really required for working in one way replication . i tried to add the following properties in slave side

```
auto.config.database=false
```

but it stops the synchronisation itself,and my entries in master sym_ tables as follws

```
delete from sym_trigger_router;
delete from sym_trigger;
delete from sym_router;
delete from sym_channel where channel_id in ('item');
delete from sym_node_group_link;
delete from sym_node_group;
delete from sym_node_host;
delete from sym_node_identity;
delete from sym_node_security;
delete from sym_node;



insert into sym_channel 
(channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, enabled, description)
values('item', 1, 100000, 1, 'Item and pricing data');

insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('corp');
insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('store');

insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('corp', 'store', 'W');
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('store', 'corp', 'P');



insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_table_name,channel_id,last_update_time,create_time)
values('item','item','item',current_timestamp,current_timestamp);



insert into sym_router 
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('corp_2_store', 'corp', 'store', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into sym_router 
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('store_2_corp', 'store', 'corp', 'default',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);



insert into sym_trigger_router 
(trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('item','corp_2_store', 100, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);



insert into sym_node (node_id,node_group_id,external_id,sync_enabled,sync_url,schema_version,symmetric_version,database_type,database_version,heartbeat_time,timezone_offset,batch_to_send_count,batch_in_error_count,created_at_node_id) 
 values ('000','corp','000',1,null,null,null,null,null,current_timestamp,null,0,0,'000');
insert into sym_node (node_id,node_group_id,external_id,sync_enabled,sync_url,schema_version,symmetric_version,database_type,database_version,heartbeat_time,timezone_offset,batch_to_send_count,batch_in_error_count,created_at_node_id) 
 values ('001','store','001',1,null,null,null,null,null,current_timestamp,null,0,0,'000');



insert into sym_node_security (node_id,node_password,registration_enabled,registration_time,initial_load_enabled,initial_load_time,created_at_node_id) 
 values ('000','5d1c92bbacbe2edb9e1ca5dbb0e481',0,current_timestamp,0,current_timestamp,'000');
insert into sym_node_security (node_id,node_password,registration_enabled,registration_time,initial_load_enabled,initial_load_time,created_at_node_id) 
 values ('001','5d1c92bbacbe2edb9e1ca5dbb0e481',1,null,1,null,'000');


insert into sym_node_identity values ('000');
```

if slave side not required sym_ tables please help me to avoid

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about `sym_` not `sys_` tables, aren't you?

Yes, you need the `sym_` tables at the destination node. For example, without the `sym_node` your destination node wont be able to register and held the registration with the source node. `sym_incoming_batch` holds all batches of data synced from the destination server etc.

Answer (score 3):

auto.config.database just tells SymmetricDS that you are going to manage the creation and maintenance of the SymmetricDS tables yourself.  They are still required.   However, you can put the SymmetricDS tables in a different catalog (database) than the target tables.

There is also a yet undocumented feature to setup up a generic jdbc data loader and use a small local H2 database as the SymmetricDS database.   This option is only for one-way synchronization to the client only.